# Wikipedia pretty table css

Tags: html, css

Can any one help me with the css to have a table that looks similar to [this table](http://science1.files.wordpress.com/2008/12/density1.jpg?w=311&h=123)? Thanks.

Because I'm using a WordPress.com blog, I don't have access to the `<head>`, so I've taken [Marty's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196403/wikipedia-pretty-table-css/6196482#6196482) and converted it to this:

```
<table style="border-collapse: collapse;">
    <tbody valign="middle">
        <tr style="background: #EEE;">
            <td style="padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #AAA;">title</td>
            <td style="padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #AAA;">title</td>
            <td style="padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #AAA;">title</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #AAA;">title</td>
            <td style="padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #AAA;">title</td>
            <td style="padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #AAA;">title</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #AAA;">title</td>
            <td style="padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #AAA;">title</td>
            <td style="padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #AAA;">title</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: So to be clear, you want a CSS style that mimics this image? http://science1.files.wordpress.com/2008/12/density1.jpg?w=311&h=123

Comment: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/08/13/top-10-css-table-designs/ have you seen this page?:

Comment: No, I havent. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @Marty Wallace: Thanks for your help! I am using wordpress.com so I don't have access to the `<head></head>` tags so I used inline. I'll update the question with the code to show you what I did. Thanks again.

Comment: @Zeynel inline is more than sufficient. Putting it in the head is a strong convention, but not an absolute requirement (well, not to the browser)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**CSS:**

```
table.mytable
{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table.mytable td
{
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #AAA;
}

tr.head
{
    background: #EEE;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<table class="mytable">
    <tbody valign="middle">
        <tr class="head">
            <td>title</td>
            <td>title</td>
            <td>title</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>content</td>
            <td>content</td>
            <td>content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>content</td>
            <td>content</td>
            <td>content</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The key ingredient here I think would be `border-collapse`.

Comment: That would be at least one key ingredient. I think really the OP needs to learn more about table styling and less about "how to match this one chart" tho ;)

Comment: @MartyWallace I know, that's why I gave you +1 ;)

Comment: @jcolebrand: I agree with you; but I tend to learn more from specific examples.

Comment: I had the same learning style, but I should have added a little more clarification than I did (none).

Comment: @jcolebrand Too lazy, but **edit** can be used by anyone here ;)

Comment: @Marty Haha, point noted. I figured you had a specific clarification in mind ;)